# How to detect a long press on a button/image

Tags: javascript, iphone, dom, cordova, dom-events

I am working on a phonegap project. I need to implement a long press event. How can we detect long press on a image/button using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#target').mousedown(function() {
  alert('Handler for .mousedown() called.');
  //start a timer
});

$('#target').mouseup(function() {
  alert('Handler for .mouseup() called.');
  //stop the timer and decide on long click

});
```

Comment: I don't like this answer. If this is being done on a mobile then it wont give you the behavior you're looking for. When you long press on most apps after holding for some amount of time the phone will pop open a context menu, vibrate, or do whatever it was going to do. It doesn't wait for you to release. Your javascript should do the same.

Answer (score 1):

One way that comes in my mind is:

1. In the start of the onclick event, record the time, this gives you the time of the first click.
2. Then check the time span. Suppose, you say 5 seconds time span is a long press event. If check is success, this is a long press event.

Answer (score 0):

head-on solution:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const info = document.querySelector("h3");
let time;
btn.onmousedown = () => {
  time = new Date(Date.now()).getSeconds();
  setTimeout(() => {
    let timecurrent = new Date(Date.now()).getSeconds();
    if (timecurrent - time == 5) {
      info.innerText = "yes pressed";
      time = undefined;
    }
  }, 5000);
}
btn.onmouseup = () => {
  time = undefined;
  info.innerText = "no pressed";
}
```

```html
<button>press me</button>
<h3>No pressed</h3>
```

Function solution:

```js
function catchLongPress(element, delay) {
  const elem = document.querySelector(element);
  let time;
  elem.onmousedown = () => {
    time = new Date(Date.now()).getSeconds();
    setTimeout(() => {
      let timecurrent = new Date(Date.now()).getSeconds();
      if (timecurrent - time == delay) {
        alert("yes pressed");
        time = undefined;
      }
    }, delay * 1000);
  }
  elem.onmouseup = () => {
    time = undefined;
    alert("no pressed");
  }
}
catchLongPress("button", 2);
```

```html
<button>press me</button>
<h3>No pressed</h3>
```